# Pass file downloaded via URL to Stream (without WebClient)

Tags: uwp, stream

I'm building an UWP app (HoloLens), and am running into a problem with streaming files downloaded from an URL. I had written a piece of code that worked perfectly, where I use WebClient.Download Data to get the file into a Stream, until I tried building and realized the WebClient class is not available in UWP apps.

In other words: how can I download a file from an URL and pass it into a Stream (to use in my BinaryReader) in an UWP app?

The code I ran:

```cs
using (Stream stream = GetStreamFromUrl(filePath))
{
    using (var binaryStream = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
        DoStuffWithBinaryStream();
    }
}

private static Stream GetStreamFromUrl(string url)
{
    byte[] imageData = null;

    using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
        imageData = wc.DownloadData(url);

    return new MemoryStream(imageData);
}
```

Comment: Did you look at `HttpClient`?

Answer (score 1):

As Peter Torr- MSFT said you could  use `HttpClient` to get the stream from `URL`.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{             
    try
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri("XXXXXX"));

        if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                //do some stuff
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

For more, please refer to [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient).